# R: dplyr does not work with spark due to memory problems

Tags: r, apache-spark

I'm trying to calculate the time difference measured in seconds between two columns of a data frame using dplyr. My data frame has been loaded this way:

```
connection <- spark_connect(master = 'local')
complete.data <- spark_read_csv(sc, "D:/mydata.csv")
```

example dataframe:

```
              start_time             end_time 
                  <dttm>                <dttm>
 1   2017-01-09 10:13:28   2017-01-09 10:25:45 
 2   2017-01-09 10:32:27   2017-01-09 10:36:01
 3   2017-01-09 10:38:20   2017-01-09 10:42:05
```

when I launch this the variable end_time is existing:

```
> complete.data %>% select(end_time)
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 1]
  end_time
  <dttm>              
1 2017-01-09 10:13:28 
2 2017-01-09 10:32:27 
3 2017-01-09 10:38:20 
4 etc..
```

but when I want to run this command the variable end_time is non-existent

```
> complete.data %>% mutate(idletime = difftime(end_time, lag(start_time), units = "mins"))
Error in as.POSIXct(time1) : object 'end_time' not found
```

example output:

```
         start_time              end_time       idletime
             <dttm>                 <dttm>          <???>
2017-01-09 10:13:28    2017-01-09 10:25:45             89 (12 minutes and 17 seconds is 89 seconds)
```

Comment: In your example dataframe you have `end_time` and `start_time`, however you then reference `end_date`?. Your code works if you use `end_time` and `start_time`.

Comment: it is my transcription error, now I have corrected