# R: how to manage a variable in dttm format

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a big problem with a variable in my data frame. The variable would be in `'dttm'` format.

```
                    data        
                  <dttm>   
 1   2017-01-09 10:13:28  
 2   2017-01-09 10:32:27  
 3   2017-01-09 10:38:20
```

I don't know this type of format and I would like to change it to a more common and manageable format. I'm using spark and apparently by launching the command `df$data` it is not possible to get the list of values ​​except by launching `df %>% select(data)` with dplyr

Comment: That's a `datetime` class, and is very common and a very good way to manage datetime data. Perhaps you should let us know what you're trying to do with that data that is giving your problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dttm is a R standard datetime datatype. more manageable is subjective, depends on what you are going to do afterwards.

it sounds like you are having issue displaying the data when in spark via `df$data`.
I don't think its an issue as R can still process it, there's probably a parsing bug by spark.

you can convert it to string using `strftime`
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html

Comment: I would like to calculate the time difference between two dates [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58592954/r-dplyr-does-not-work-with-spark-due-to-memory-problems)

Comment: you can use `difftime`.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/difftime

Answer (score 1):

Datetime formats can be manipulated with the [lubridate package](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/) and stored in whatever way you need!